# Problems while upgrading laravel-elixir from 5 to 6 version

Tags: webpack, vue.js, laravel-elixir, vue-component

After upgrading laravel elixir to 6.0 version in console errors appear like: 
`[Vue warn]: Attributes ":model.sync", "key", "name" are ignored on component <wysiwyg> because the component is a fragment instance:`. 
I already read this [vue doc](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Fragment-Instance). 
Though while i have used laravel-elixir 5.0 everything was alright. 
Also, i changed browserify on webpack.
Template to the component include using this:

```
template: require('./template.html')
```

How i can fix this error?